# How to set frame of MNColorPicker?

Tags: iphone, ipad, frame, uipopovercontroller, color-picker

I am using MNColorPicker in my universal iOS application. I am presenting it in a UIPopoverController in iPad and its working fine.

Now I need to implement similar functionality in iPhone but as iPhone doesn't support UIPopoverController I am using a third party pop over like control [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView). Hen I present the pop over without setting the size of MNColorPicker manually then it is presented properly but the size of pop over becomes very big for an iPhone and when I try to change the size of MNColorPicker, it doesn't get presented properly. Bellow is the screenshot for the same.

[image: Improper pop over]

Please give me some pointers as to how I can resize MNColorPicker so that it can be presented in a CMPopTipView properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the frames given in function

```
- (void)_layoutViewsForInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

in class MNColorPicker and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BFColorPickerPopover control for iPhone.

Comment: Hi Mage, thanks for the response but the control mentioned by you is for Mac OS X and not for iOS.